# Sample Covariance for 2 vectors

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate sample covariance between these two vectors. I defined a function with two input variables. I don't know if it is correct? Also my formula for sample covariance won't run. Can anyone help me write it out in R?

```
  xv = c(1., 5.5, 7.8, 4.2, -2.7, -5.4, 8.9)
  yv = c(0.1, 1.5, 0.8, -4.2, 2.7, -9.4, -1.9)
  sampleCov= function(x,y){ 
    cov(xv,yv) = frac{sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\mu_x)(y_i-\mu_y)}{n-1}].
    return (Cov(xv,yv)
  }
```

Comment: Your function doesn't work because it has syntax errors.  Fix those first.  Have you tried the `cov` function?

Comment: To be honest i'm very new to programming and dont know how to fix them. I've been stuck on this for a while. How can I improve my function?

Comment: You can improve your function by reading the [introductory manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html), especially [Section 10, Writing your own functions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions).

Comment: For starters, don't use LaTeX markup as R code; it just won't parse. It is hard to know where to begin here because you have got totally the wrong end of the stick if you thought R could even begin to understand that code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a base function in R called `cov` that does exactly what you want, but if you want to write a function (no need to do that) you can try the following:

```
COV<- function(x,y) {
  if(length(x)!=length(y)) {stop('x must have the same length as y ')}
  x.bar <- mean(x)
  y.bar <- mean(y)
  N <- length(x)

  Cov <- (sum((x-x.bar)*(y-y.bar))) / (N-1)
  return(Cov)
}

COV(xv, yv)
[1] 8.697381

cov(xv, yv)
[1] 8.697381
```

As you can see `COV` gives the same result as `cov` so you don't have to write a function for that.

Besides, the body of your function doesn't have R syntax, instead you wrote LaTex syntax which are not the same.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the internal `cov()` function:

```
xv <- c(1., 5.5, 7.8, 4.2, -2.7, -5.4, 8.9)
yv <- c(0.1, 1.5, 0.8, -4.2, 2.7, -9.4, -1.9)
cov(xv, yv)

R> cov(xv, yv)
[1] 8.697381
```

If you really want to reinvent the wheel:

```
sampleCov <- function(x,y){
    stopifnot(identical(length(x), length(y)))
    sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y))) / (length(x) - 1)
}

R> sampleCov(xv, yv)
[1] 8.697381
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you can compute the covariance of two matrices using the following formula:

```
  cov_xv_yv <- 1/(length(xv)-1) * t(xv) %*% yv
```

Which is 1/(N-1) times the matrix product of the transpose of matrix xv and the matrix yv.

This form is easily extendable to many dimensions.